# $n$-th derivative of $\frac{e^{2\pi i Tx} - 1}{2 \pi i T x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis

Let $T$ be a real number greater than $1$. Let
$$
f(x) =  \frac{e^{2\pi i Tx} - 1}{2 \pi i T x}. 
$$
I am interested in obtaining an upper bound for $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} | f^{(n)}(x) |$
where $f^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$th derivative. I have tried to do this by induction, but it's getting quite messy... If any one can help me with this it would be appreciated!

Comment: Here’s a possibility: $f^{(n)}(x)=\int_0^1{(2i\pi Tu)^ne^{2i\pi Txu}\,du}$.

Comment: very nice! thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m turning my comment into an answer.

A straightforward computation shows that $f(x)=\int_0^1{e^{2i\pi Tux}\,du}$.

Because the integrand is a a smooth function of $(u,x)$ and we’re integrating on a compact interval, we can differentiate under the integral, so $f^{(n)}(x)=\int_0^1{(2i\pi Tu)^ne^{2i\pi Tux}\, du}$.

In particular $\|f^{(n)}\|_{\infty}=\frac{(2\pi T)^n}{n+1}$.